# Producto bloqueado por limete de venta

Tags: php, mysqli

Realizando un proyecto me mandaron a bloquear productos que pasen el límite de venta, me explico:

Tengo dos tablas, `producto` y `ventas`, donde hay un listado de productos a la venta la cual si alcanza el límite de venta `diaria` no se pueda mostrar en en listado...

Si un producto `camisa` se a vendido en el dia por la cantidad de `20000` y el límite es igual, que no se muestre en pantalla

no se como realizar la consulta [sql](/questions/tagged/sql), estoy trabajando con [php](/questions/tagged/php) y [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql).

Gracias

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for producto
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `producto`;
CREATE TABLE `producto` (
  `id_pro` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre_pro` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imagen_pro` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_pro` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_pro`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for ventas
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ventas`;
CREATE TABLE `ventas` (
  `id_ventas` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_producto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_venta` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `monto_venta` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_ventas`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar cómo están formadas las dos tablas, para saber la forma en que almacenas las ventas de los productos?

Comment: producto
>id_pro int
>nombre_pro
>imagen_pro
>status_pro

ventas
>id_ventas
>id_producto
>fecha_venta
>monto_venta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre una solución del siguiente modo:

- un campo **`cantidad`** que podría estar en la tabla `ventas` o en otra. Eso dependerá de la estructura de tu base de datos. Aquí lo he puesto en la misma tabla `ventas` por simplificar.
- aplicas la función `SUM` sobre dicho campo para calcular la cantidad de productos vendidos.
- usas `GROUP BY` para que la suma se haga teniendo en cuenta dos criterios:  `id_pro` y `fecha_venta`,  de modo que te sume las ventas de cada producto por fecha específica.
- finalmente usas `HAVING` para evaluar que dicha cantidad sea menor que 20,000

Te dejo este ejemplo, si quieres aplicar más filtros como `WHERE fecha_venta = '....'` agregar más columnas en el SELECT, poner el campo `cantidad` en otra tabla, etc, lo podrás hacer sin problemas. Eso dependerá de tus necesidades. El objetivo es que veas cómo funciona, analizando la **Query 1**.

Verás en los `INSERT` que he puesto dos ventas de arroz de 10,000 cada una el 1 de mayo, y verás que el producto arroz no sale en la consulta de ese día. :)

### EDIT INCLUYENDO PRODUCTOS NO VENDIDOS

[**`DEMO SQL Fiddle`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b49b9/8)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS producto; 
CREATE TABLE producto
  ( id_pro int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    nombre_pro varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,  
    imagen_pro varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,  
    status_pro varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id_pro) 
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO producto (id_pro,nombre_pro) 
  VALUES 
  (1,"Arroz"),
  (2,"Carne"),
  (3,"No vendido") 
  ;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ventas; 
CREATE TABLE ventas
  ( id_ventas int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    id_producto int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
    fecha_venta date DEFAULT NULL, 
    monto_venta decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL, 
    cantidad int DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id_ventas) 
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO 
  ventas (id_ventas, id_producto, fecha_venta, monto_venta, cantidad)
  VALUES 
  (1,1,'2017-05-01',1000.00,10000),
  (2,1,'2017-05-01',1000.00,10000),
  (3,1,'2017-05-02',700.00,7000),
  (4,2,'2017-05-01',10.00,1),
  (5,2,'2017-05-01',350.00,33),
  (6,2,'2017-05-02',723.00,89);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT p.nombre_pro, v.fecha_venta, SUM(v.cantidad) AS total  FROM
producto p
LEFT JOIN ventas v 
ON p.id_pro=v.id_producto
GROUP BY p.id_pro,v.fecha_venta
HAVING total < 20000 OR total IS NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b49b9/8/0)**:

```
| nombre_pro |           fecha_venta |  total |
|------------|-----------------------|--------|
|      Arroz | May, 02 2017 00:00:00 |   7000 |
|      Carne | May, 01 2017 00:00:00 |     34 |
|      Carne | May, 02 2017 00:00:00 |     89 |
| No vendido |                (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: Padre antes todo gracias por tomarse el tiempo, pero.... siempre el bendito pero...la idea es: si un **producto alcanza su venta diaria no sale en pantalla** ese dia pero los demas salen...

Comment: @RichardMartinez De nada. Si te fijas bien eso es lo que hace la consulta. En el ejemplo arroz tuvo 20,000 ventas el 1 de mayo y no sale en los resultados. Aplicando esa consulta a los productos que salen en pantalla tendrás solo aquellos que tengan menos de 20,000 ventas.

Comment: Hola, ya me da pena, pero...**No tengo venta el dia x no salen en pantalla** solo sale los productos que se han vendidos y la **idea es que solo aparezacan _todos_ los producto con venta <20000** agrege mas producto a la lista sin venta y no salen.... :(  :(

Comment: @RichardAMartinezG Eso se resuelve agregando esto al final del HAVING: `OR total IS NULL`. He editado la respuesta con esa posibilidad.

Comment: 'WHERE v.fecha_venta = '2017-05-05'' Padre le agrege esto para realizar ventas el otro dia y no sale nada en pantalla...:( :(
[Mas test ](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5323c6/4)

Comment: Si te fijas en los **datos de prueba** que hay introducidos, **en la fecha 2017-05-05 no hay registrado ningún producto**, por eso no te sale nada.

Comment: ok, pero necesito que para el día siguente todos los productos se muestren en pantalla, ya que la venta se limita al **por dia de venta** del producto **se vendio Aceite suma total por dia _2017-05-50_ de 20000 no se presenta en pantalla pero el día _2017-05-06_ se muestra en pantalla para la venta**

Comment: @RichardAMartinezG es que eso es ya **otra pregunta**. Stackoverflow funciona _por preguntas_, no sé si me explico. Aquí tú planteaste que querías que te bloqueara en un día determinado los productos que **ese día tuviesen ventas superior a 20,000**, dicho problema ha sido resuelto. Entonces ahora si surge otra necesidad lo mejor es plantear **otra** pregunta. La consulta filtra las ventas superiores a 20,000. Luego preguntaste por los `NULL`, también resuelto. Creo que podemos dar por respondida esta pregunta ¿no?

Comment: Si Padre, tiene razón... podemos dar por respondida esta pregunta...y gracias por su tiempo, saludos y mil bendiciones.

Comment: De nada @RichardAMartinezG ¿Puedes marcar la flecha de cotejo a la izquierda de la respuesta que consideres? Es la manera de indicar que la pregunta no sigue abierta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas un campo adicional para decir la cantidad de productos que tienes en tu stock o inventario. Este campo tiene que ser de valor numerico (numeric) o entero (int).

Cuando el valor de ese producto sea 0. Usted prepara la imposibilidad de comprar este producto algo asi como..

```
<?php if ($producto[x] == 0) { $mensaje = "No hay existencia de stock";  }; ?>
```

Luego usted enviara eso a donde usted le corresponda ese mensaje de acuerdo a su infraestructura de codigo.

Si necesita mayor referencia no olvide hacerla.
Tambien podemos ofrecerte eso que pides por si se superan los 2000:

```
    <?php if ($producto[x] >= 2000) { /* Aqui la instruccion de saltarse.  */ }; ?>
```

y si estas en bucle.. entonces

```
        <?php if ($producto[x] >= 2000) { continue; }; ?>
```

Esto con la intencion de que usted se haga el salto de imprimir en su plantilla o vista (mvc) el producto.

Comment: la idea es sumar las venta de productos la cual tienen un limite de venta diaria todo los producto [30.000 x dia] y llega a ese limite el producto no se muestre en pantalla. asi como es estatus del producto es 1 para la venta y 0 no sale, asi pero con la suma de venta. Necesito es el query o consulta SQL

Answer (score 0):

1) Crea un campo adicional llamado cantidad de ventas en tu tabla de producto, que sea de valor entero (int) y valor no nulo.

2) Prepara una sentencia MYSQL  similar a la que te ofrecere a continuacion para saber que cantidad de tiene el producto:

```
SELECT cantidad_de_ventas FROM tabla_de_productos WHERE '$elnombre_de_mi_producto'.
```

Traduccion: Selecciona el campo cantidad_de_ventas de la tabla "tabla_de_productos" con el valor '$elnombre_de_mi_producto".

3) Luego cuando se vayan sumando las ventas y se realicen añade una sentencia algo asi como

```
INSERT INTO tabla_de_productos (cantidad_de_ventas) Values ('$elvalor_actual + 1')
```

La variable $valor_actual es la que obtendremos con la sentencia anterior de mysql. y por supuesto se le suma 1 ... Ahora....

Añades un condicional en tu php para chequear si el producto se puede mostrar

```
        <?php if ($producto[x] >= 2000 ) { continue }; ?>
```

Esto en alucion de que tu usas un bucle sea un foreach o while para imprimir esa lista de productos y saltaras de que se muestre.

Comment: No la puedo hacer por producto, acuerdate que es por venta del producto diario, hoy se vendio 2000 el producto xX no sale en pantalla, pero mañana si

Comment: Bueno, facil haces un cronjob con tu servidor que se ejecute un codigo para que el cantidad_de_ventas se limpie a las 12 de la noche. Siguiendo la misma idea que yo te di. Para que ya por dia no tengas ese problema.

Comment: Negativo, ya que hay que guardar historial, solo me queda realizar otra tabla donde cada vez que compren un producto sume la cantdad vendida+las vendidas y de alli tomar el limite de cada producto por dia.. sera?

Comment: Por cada venta que hagas diaria puedes simplemente crear una funcion en php que traiga segun la fecha y el producto la cantidad de productos que se vendieron, ya que si tu por ejemplo llegas a los 2000 productos. Se supone que debe existir una tabla donde se almacen las ventas segun el cliente. entonces alli esta la clave. relaciona esa table segun la fecha de la que se ha hecho la venta. haces un conteo cuantas veces esa fecha para el caso del dia como "hoy" se ha hecho la compra y si supera los 2000 no permites que se muestre .. y asi mantienes un historial y mas control